# how to carry forward values from one to another row in Python Pandas, I am trying to replicate the functionality of SAS retain statment

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to replicate the SAS retain statement functionality in Python, I could able to achieve that by processing the data from using .iloc method as below.

```
for s in range(len(DF)):  
    if s==0 :
        DF.p_V1.iloc[s] = DF.V1.iloc[s]  
    else:
        DF.V1_l1.iloc[s]=DF.p_V1.iloc[s-1]
        DF.p_d_V1.iloc[s]= DF.V1_l1.iloc[s]-DF.LTR_l1.iloc[s]
        DF.p_V1.iloc[s] = DF.V1_l1.iloc[s] + DF.p_d_V1.iloc[s]
```

is there any better way we can achieve this than using .iloc?

Comment: can you provide sample input/output?

Comment: Use `pd.shift()`

Comment: here is the sample output data.. we have circular reference in it.. for  achieving that I used .iloc to go back and refer the previous values. V1 p_V1 V1_l1 LTR_l1 p_d_V1
1 0.559108547 0.559108547 0  0
2  0.156922766 0.559108547 0.961294329 -0.402185781
3  -0.760403967 0.156922766 1.074249499 -0.917326733
4  -2.739781246 -0.760403967 1.218973312 -1.979377279
5  -6.829140219 -2.739781246 1.349577728 -4.089358974
6  -15.14022751 -6.829140219 1.481947069 -8.311087288
7  -31.8788871 -15.14022751 1.598432088 -16.7386596
8  -65.35620629 -31.8788871 1.598432088 -33.47731919

Comment: here is the sample output data.. we have circular reference in it.. for  achieving that I used .iloc to go back and refer the previous values. V1 p_V1 V1_l1 LTR_l1 p_d_V1
1 0.559108547 0.559108547 0  0
2  0.156922766 0.559108547 0.961294329 -0.402185781
3  -0.760403967 0.156922766 1.074249499 -0.917326733
4  -2.739781246 -0.760403967 1.218973312 -1.979377279
5  -6.829140219 -2.739781246 1.349577728 -4.089358974
6  -15.14022751 -6.829140219 1.481947069 -8.311087288
7  -31.8788871 -15.14022751 1.598432088 -16.7386596
8  -65.35620629 -31.8788871 1.598432088 -33.47731919